# Plugin Development/ Stop CSS clashes.

Tags: plugin-development, css

I have searched all over and I am a little confused about my first plugin that I am developing.

I created a shortcode that the user can use on any page they create. The issue is that on a lot of themes the plugin gets pushed out of container width.

I think that most templates are 960px wide, and my plugin is 800px wide (I am not looking for advise on developing with em, percentages, etc. this is a fixed sized plugin).

How can I stop css clashes? I want the container width to be 960px wide. There must be some default id's and classes that I can overwrite in my css.

I would imagine themes use standard naming conventions in order to allow users to switch at anytime.

EDIT: I would also like to remove any sidebar() that is showing on the page...help!?

Anyway, does anyone have advice on this?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know, and can't control, the content width, then your Plugin shouldn't *assume* any given content width.

Also, even though templates may be 960px in *total* width, the *content* width will almost assuredly be less than that.

If you *must* apply explicit width to your output, you could try returning the value set for the `$content_width` global, and then use that value in your generated CSS.

Comment: What would your suggestion be for a standard width of a plugin going in the main content area of a page? I need to control the width of this plugin because it is somewhat complex and need to make sure formatting stays consistent.

Comment: I would recommend re-thinking your output, so that it is not dependent upon a specific content width; or else, base your assumption on a much smaller content width, such as 400px, that is more likely to be well-accommodated by the vast majority of Themes.

Answer (score 1):

Well really you shouldn't be looking to modify the theme layout, your's is the addon after all and it should be up to the theme author/admin to make sure their theme works with your plugin if they want to use it.

In any case have you tried using the css !important declaration on you container?

```
#mycontainer{
    width:960px!important;
}
```

That should force your container's width, then it's up to whoever is using it to make sure their theme is compatible.

Comment: Such indiscriminate and arbitrary use of `!important` is evil, and Plugins should never do such a thing. :)

Comment: I agree entirely :) just offering a possible solution :)